# How to use join to combine different tables from database in asp.net mvc to export excel?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, closedxml

One module has a date-type "Year"(ExtractionViewModel) that must be an output on Excel on a column, One module has Week(WeekDetail) and other module has Schedule(ModelId) its datatype. All of these must be an output on a column as excel format, i am trying to use join on my method below

This is what I have based on model and controller as follows:

````
// Model
public class ExtractionViewModel
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public int WeekNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public  class WeekDetails {
public int WeekNum { get; set; }


}

public  class Schedule{
public System.Guid ModelId { get; set; }

 }
// Controller
public IList<ExtractionViewModel> GetExtractionViewModels()
{
    ProductionManagementEntities db = new ProductionManagementEntities();

    var scheduleList = (from s in db.Schedules
                        join m in db.Models on s.ScheduleId equals m.Name
                        select new ExtractionViewModel
                        {
                              Year = s.,
                              Week =
                            
                        }).ToList();
    return scheduleList;
}

public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    var v = new GridView();
    v.DataSource = this.GetExtractionViewModels();
    v.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ExtractionRecords.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
    v.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    return View("List");
}
```
````

Comment: I have one database, i want to join two different tables, "schedule and models"

Comment: How are the tables "schedule" and "models" related, please, [edit] your question explaining the model of your database - in this case, the schema of the "schedule" and "models" tables, add some data and the desired results. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Gcobani Mkontwana: Good example of using **Joining**: [https://entityframework.net/joining](https://entityframework.net/joining). You didn't include declarations of the `Model` and the `Schedule`. Therefore does not clear what is the join properties should be...

Comment: @GcobaniMkontwana This seems to be a database or EntityFramework issue and not related to ClosedXML at all.

Comment: @Francois yes it is enity framework, the data on excel sheet is not correct and finding some challenges